# Console.log the output of an async function directly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am running this async function:

```
async function getIngress(namespace) {
  try {
    const result = await k8sIngressApi.listNamespacedIngress(namespace, true);
    return result.body.items[0].spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].path;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.response.body);
  }
}
console.log(getIngress(argument);
```

The console log only prints a promise. Is there a way I can access the returned value of the promise outside of a function like I am trying to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can! I'll give you three ways:

**Using async function**

```
async function logPromiseResult() {
  console.log(await getIngress(argument));
}
```

**Using .then callback**

```
getIngress(argument).then(result => console.log(result));
```

**Or you just can change that function definition**

```
async function getIngress(namespace) {
    let response;
    try {
        const result = await k8sIngressApi.listNamespacedIngress(namespace, true);
        response = result.body.items[0].spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].path;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.response.body);
    }
    console.log(response);
    return response;
}
```

Hope that this is what you need and it helps you!

Answer (score 3):

`await` should work.

```
console.log(await getIngress(argument));
```

Comment: Assuming the `console.log` is located in an async function otherwise he would get an error message for using `await` outside `async`.

Comment: Yup, you are right

Answer (score 2):

1) getIngress(argument).then(console.log)

or the same: getIngress(argument).then(res => console.log(res))

2) await getIngress(argument), but it works only inside async function:

you should make async IIFE if your outside function isn't async or it is top level:

```
(async () => {
  console.log(await getIngress(argument))
})();
```